# Grab images from wordpress media library category

Tags: wordpress, media, wp-list-categories

Just picking up wordpress as of late and I am trying to create a homepage slide show. I am creating a custom theme for a client and I want to be able to categorize media in the media library, so I am using [this plugin](https://sites.google.com/site/medialibarycategories/) to add categories so I can just pull the images from the "homepageBanner" gallery that I created.

When I pull images from my media library on my template via get_posts(), get_children() or do_shortcodes(), they all don't give me a property on the objects that are returned to determine what category they are in.

I imagine this has been done before (without a plugin), and seems like an incredibly easy task, however where I look and search, all I am finding are plug-ins.

Comment: If you upload image via the media library in the post/page, then they are associated to that page or post. Can you confirm that's where you are uploading images? As opposed to the whole site 'media library' link on the main lefthand menu.

Comment: Sure. If I upload media to just the post/page, then it's in the post and I don't want that. If I used it as a featured image, I can only put one up at a time. My thinking was that I could just have the user upload a few photos to their library, give them a category and then pull them via code and render them into my slide show code.

Comment: And does in order to use an image does it have to be tied to a post/page?

Comment: Well theres no need for the image categories if its tied to the page, you don't have to insert the images into the post. You can use get_children and pass the post_parent parameter with the ID for the post.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the media library categories plugin then check out the function get_category_archive located in the media-categories.php. it is used in the taxonomy-media_category.php to pull archived images. you could create a custom function in your themes function.php that does something similar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the: media-library-categories.1.0.6 plugin, then you can simply do the following to echo out an unordered list containing all your images for a specific media category (replace "11" with the ID of the media category you want to display)

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[mediacategories categories="11"]');  ?>
```